database increase id when occur exception
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String dataType;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String identifier;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private String email;
}

Hello , when I hit HTTP POST and occur ConstraintValidationException/DataIntegrity database increase ID +1 ,
example I added first user ID 1,
I try to add user two and occur exception - increased ID and user not added,
then I try to add user three and he has ID 3 instead of ID 2

could you perform your insertions using a transaction and rollback if the constraint validation exception occurs? Show how you perform your insertions?

If I add transactional on method level and add verify like FindByExistIdentifier - could be race condition yes ?
